# Both jQuery filter() and find() Returns Error on AJAX Reponse

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My AJAX returns either a HTML all wrapped in `<div class = 'Post'>....</div>` or just `No new data yet`.

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "/mysite/load_latest/",
  type: "POST",
  data: { user_id : userID },
  dataType: "html"
});
request.done(function( msg ){   
    console.log(msg);
    var class1 = $(msg).filter(".Post");
    console.log(class1);            
});
```

**I want to check if `.Post` exist in the returned HTML** but it returns this error: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <div class = 'Post'>...content...</div>`

I tried `$(msg).find(".Post");` but it returns the same error.

Comment: What should msg return??

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef: An HTML: `<div class = 'Post'> content goes here </div>`

Comment: its not yet html .. its just string until you display it as an html

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef: How can this help me solve this issue?

Comment: Not able to reproduce your issue... http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/79ukprre/1/ . Would you mind setting up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make a new element, append your response to it, then search for desired element:

```
request.done(function( msg ) {
    var element =
        // make a new element on the fly
        $('<div></div>')

        // put the `msg` response inside it
        .html(msg)

        // now search for `.Post` element
        .find('.Post')
    ;

    // the length will be `0` or more
    alert(element.length);
});
```

Comment: This did it but I wrapped another `div` around `<div class='Post'>...</div>` and it give me what I want. Yours did it too. The difference is: mine is done at back end and yours at front end. Is any of this advantageous over the other?

Comment: There is no difference, both of them are OK. But I will choose the front end way, which will prevent unwanted mistakes (if the server doesn't wrap the code correctly).

Answer (score 0):

for example in html

```
<div class="msg_html"></div>
```

in your code

```
request.done(function( msg ){   
    $('.msg_html').html(msg);
    $('.Post').css('background','yellow');
    alert('Now your Post class has a background yellow if its a content in it');         
});
```

Comment: You should search inside your element, not the whole document. Also appending the response to real HTML tag is not a good idea.

Comment: Sorry but your answer is far from what my question seeks for.